# Running specified lines of R code on command

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose I am working on line 700 of an R script, and I want to re-run lines 300-500 without scrolling *way* up. Is there an R function for this functionality?

Comment: retracting my comment - but i think that splitting up into multiple scripts and using `source()` is a better workflow.

Comment: @Phil I would tend to agree - I wouldn't have an R file with that many lines in the first place if I could avoid it, but sometimes there are situations where this may come in handy; perhaps debugging someone else's code, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in R studio, you can use the following function:

```r
run_lines <- function(x) {
  editor <- rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()
  start <- rstudioapi::document_position(min(x), 1)
  end <- rstudioapi::document_position(max(x) + 1, 1)
  range <- rstudioapi::document_range(start, end)
  rstudioapi::setSelectionRanges(range, editor$id)
  selection <- rstudioapi::primary_selection(
    rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext())$text
  source(textConnection(selection))
}
```

Then, suppose I have the following source file open as the active document in my editor window:

```r
x <- 1
y <- 2
print(x + y)

print("hello world")

a <- 3
b <- 5
print(a + b)
```

If I want to run only lines 5 to 9, I can type in the console:

```r
run_lines(5:9)
#> [1] "hello world"
#> [1] 8
```

Or, if I just want to run the first 3 lines, I can do:

```r
run_lines(1:3)
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks. @Allan, do you know how to get a position by looking for at certain words?. Is there another way to run code without selecting lines?.

Comment: @AlvaroMorales I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: by doing something like this `word_to_find <- "love"` ;`rstudioapi::document_position(word_to find, 1)`; so you get all the number lines where the word "love" is positioned in the current script.

Comment: You can get the contents of the open document window using `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$contents`, so  `grep('love', rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$contents)` will give you each line the text appears on. To get the exact location would require `regexpr` instead of `grep`. If you get stuck with this, please post a question.